# Looping through to return all the required node IDs

Tags: c#, kentico

I am kinda struggling with returning all the node ID's inside a given Treeview.

Basically I have a function which runs a query to the database using a given NodeID
and returns its Parent Node ID as shown below, which works fine and returns me the 
Parent Node ID of the Node ID which is passed through.

```
public static string Parent_ID(string NodeID)
{        
   GeneralConnection gc = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection();
   int intNodeID = Convert.ToInt32(NodeID);

   QueryDataParameters para = new QueryDataParameters();
   para.Add("@NodeID", intNodeID);

   int parent = (int)gc.ExecuteScalar("custom.product.searchForParentNodeID", para);

   return Convert.ToString(parent);              
}
```

Now the ParentID returned is actually a NodeID of the Node above. So basically 
I want to use the newly obtained ID to obtains its ParentID and keeping looping 
through the table (using the above query) till I can obtain all NodeIDs within the current level. Obviously I will be storing these NodeIDs in a StringBuilder list which I plan on using it for further checks.

Anybody have suggestions?

Comment: _'Obviously I will be storing these NodeIDs in a StringBuilder list'_ Why would this be obvious? Why wouldn't you use a `List<int>` or similar collection? Also, what is the problem? Just call the method recursively.

Comment: Hi Grant Thomas, thanks for the feedback. StringBuilder was just a suggestion but I am ok with using List<int>. In regards to the recursive method, I am not exactly sure how I would start with constructing the method. Perhaps can you give me an example or a direction?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little confusing, but maybe this will help.  You should try using the API instead of custom queries, if possible, to make hotfixes/upgrades easier in the future.  For example, if you have a Node ID and you want all of it's siblings, you can do something like this:

```
// Version 7 code, untested
var treeProvider = new TreeProvider();
var childNodeId = 1;

// Get the child Node
// Node ID, Culture, Site name
var childNodeDataSet = treeProvider.SelectNodes(childNodeId, null, CMSContext.CurrentSiteName);

if (childNodeDataSet.Items.Any())
{
    // Assuming the child node was found, get the parent ID
    var parentNodeId = childNodeDataSet.Items[0].NodeParentID;

    // Now get the children of the parent, aka the siblings
    // Site name, Culture, Combine with default culture, Where clause, Order by clause
    var siblingNodes = treeProvider.SelectNodes(CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, "/%", null, false, null, "NodeParentID = '" + parentNodeId + "'", null);
}
```

Hope that helps.